# Let V=P3(F) and let T∈L(V) given by T(a0 +a1x +a2x^2 +a3x^3)=6(a3x^3) + 2(a2x^2)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V=P3(F) and let T∈L(V) given by T(a0 +a1x +a2x^2 +a3x^3)=6(a3x^3) + 2(a2x^2). 
for all aix^i∈V and ai∈F for all i. Assume T is a linear map.

Find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of T.

My attempt:
T(a0 +a1x +a2x^2 +a3x^3)=λ(a0 +a1x +a2x^2 +a3x^3)=6(a3x^3) + 2(a2x^2)

So we get λa0 +λa1x +λa2x^2 +λa3x^3 = 6(a3x^3) + 2(a2x^2)

Which gives us λa0 +λa1x + (λ-2)a2x^2 + (λ-6)a3x^3 = 0

This implies that a0=a1=0.
So can λ=2 or λ=6?
Or do we just consider the leading coefficient, which implies that only λ=6.

Answer (score 0):

Try to proceed using the characteristic polynomial.

Find a matrix $A$ which represents the transformation with respect to some basis $\alpha$ and then the eigenvalues will be all $\lambda$ which satisfies $det(A- \lambda I)=0$.

Each $\lambda_i$ will have the correspondent eigenvectors ${v}$ determined by the equation $A[v]_\alpha = \lambda_i [v]_\alpha $. And you just solve this system to find $[v]_\alpha$ for each eigenvalue, and then, according to your choice of the basis (advice you to choice the canonical one) you find the general form of the eigenvectors.

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't the method my teacher taught us. Although I have seen that method while looking at other books. Thank you for your input.